# Adding AWS Cognito User Pool Required Attributes for Signup experience in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating Cognito User Pool using Terraform where I need to specify Requried Attributes  like `email`, `family_name` and `name` for the sign up experience so that the user will be forces to provide values for those fields while signing up. The following is my code.

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "users_pool" {
  name = "my-example-users"

  email_configuration {
    email_sending_account = "DEVELOPER"
    from_email_address    = "<from-email-address>"
    source_arn            = "<identity-arn-goes-here>" 
    
  }

  verification_message_template {
    email_subject = "Your verification code"
    email_message = "Your verification code is {####}. "
    sms_message   = "Your verification code is {####}. "
  }

  admin_create_user_config {
    invite_message_template {
      email_subject = "Your account details"
      email_message = "\nHi {username} <br/><br/>\nYour username is {username} and password is {####}.  </br><br/>\nThanks<br/>\n"
      sms_message   = "Your username is {username} and password is {####}. "
    }
    allow_admin_create_user_only = false
  }

  sms_authentication_message = "Your authentication code is {####}."

  password_policy {
    minimum_length = 8
    temporary_password_validity_days = 7
    require_lowercase = true
    require_numbers = true
    require_symbols = true
    require_uppercase = true
  }

  alias_attributes = ["email", "preferred_username"]


  username_configuration {
    case_sensitive = "true"
  }

  auto_verified_attributes = [ "email" ]

  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    name = "name"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable                  = true
    required                 = false
    string_attribute_constraints {
      max_length = 50
      min_length = 1
    }
  }

  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    name = "email"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable                  = true
    required                 = false
    string_attribute_constraints {
      max_length = 50
      min_length = 1
    }
  }

  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    name = "family_name"
    developer_only_attribute = false
    mutable                  = true
    required                 = false
    string_attribute_constraints {
      max_length = 50
      min_length = 1
    }
  }
  
  # This is a custom attribute to be added in the signup experience
  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    mutable = true
    name = "organization"
    string_attribute_constraints {
      max_length = 50
      min_length = 1
    }
  }

  tags = {...}
}
```

The expectation is something like this.

[image]

But what I get when I execute this code is the one below.

[image]

How can I make sure I have all those required attributes for the Sign Up Experience listed when I create the resource using Terraform? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

My bad. The answer is `required = "true"` in the Schema attribute.